Removing a user from the Users group does nothing? (Windows 7)
I've created a new user:
net user temp password /add

and removed it from Users:
net localgroup users temp /delete

but still temp's access permissions for a file are governed by the Users entry for that file (in Properties/Security).  In other words, even though temp is not listed in Users anymore it behaves like it's still there.  Is it supposed to be that way?  Thanks for your help.

You cannot remove a user from Users if you did they would have zero permissions on the system, use a different user group and grant that group access to the file, and revoke the permissions to Users.
